# How do I make the text inside a div fluid when browser resizes?

Tags: html, css, text, web, fluid

Ok so I have 3 main divs; Grey div which is the wrapper, Blue div which is on the left side and Orange div which is on the right side. Blue div has a fixed width and height.

My question is, how do I make the TEXT inside the Orange div fluid when browser window resizes? I dont want the whole Orange div to just jump down under the Blue div, I want the text to be fluid instead. How do I achieve this?

Thank you for your time :)

Here's a JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/op4nnmb4/7/

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: #3c3c3c;
}

.leftimg{
    width:600px;
    height: 2900px;
    background: #8cceff;
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
}

.rightside {
    background: #F96;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.projectimg {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.project-title {
    font-family: 'Abel';
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
}

.project-title .title1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.project-title .title2 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    clear: both;
    display:block;  
}

.context {
    float: left;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
    width: auto;
    margin: 20px 0 0 40px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.context p {
    font-size: 1.06rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: Define what "fluid" means to us.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it using `float` for the blue/left-hand image panel.

The orange/content panel can be kept in the flow (not floated).

I removed a lot of extraneous properties that were confusing things, but
overall, this may be close to what you need.

You should try to use semantic mark-up, for example, `h1` and `h2` instead of the more generic `span` with a class to make it behave like a block element.

```css
.wrapper {
  /* position: absolute; <-- You probably do not need this... */
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: #3c3c3c;
  overflow: auto;  /* If you want the background color to show under all the image */
}
.leftimg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #8cceff;
  float: left;
}
.rightside {
  background: #F96;
  overflow: auto;
}
.project-title {
  font-family: 'Abel';
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.project-title h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.project-title h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.context {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 20px 0 0 40px;
}
.context p {
  font-size: 1.06rem;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftimg">
    <span>I am an image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
    <div class="project-title">
      <h1>I Am Main Title</h1>
      <h2>Sub title<h2>
        </div>
        <div class="context">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do I make the ... the Orange div fluid [width] when [the] ... window resizes?

Adding `display: flex;` to wrapper will give fluid width to any element which does not have a set width;

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/op4nnmb4/9/))

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

> Flex layout is superficially similar to block layout. It lacks many of the more complex text- or document-centric properties that can be used in block layout, such as floats and columns. In return it gains simple and powerful tools for distributing space and aligning content in ways that webapps and complex web pages often need. The contents of a flex container:
>
> - can be laid out in any flow direction (leftwards, rightwards, downwards, or even upwards!)
> - can have their display order reversed or rearranged at the style layer (i.e., visual order can be independent of source and speech order)
> - can be laid out linearly along a single (main) axis or wrapped into multiple lines along a secondary (cross) axis
> - can “flex” their sizes to respond to the available space
> - can be aligned with respect to their container or each other
> - can be dynamically collapsed or uncollapsed along the main axis while preserving the container’s cross size
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#overview

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/op4nnmb4/12/

```
.wrapper {
 display:table;
}
.leftimg, .rightside{
 display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll be satisfied ignoring IE8 and Androids below 4.4, use [*Viewport Sized Typography*](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).

This way, you can let your `font-size` be 1% of the viewport size (which is the window size), horizontally if you use the `vw` unit, or vertically if you use the `vh` unit. The better part is that the text auto-resizes itself when the viewport size changes.